# How to insert custom Javascripts in Sitecore backend

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Pretty simple, I need to insert a script in Sitecores (v. 6.4) backend - how do I do it?

It doesn't matter if the script is placed inside `<head>` or `<body>`, nor does it matter if I can only specify the `src` of a `<script>` tag or if I can insert an actual Javascript snippet (the latter is preferable though).

The script needs to be inserted in the HTML when a Content Editor window is opened.

It is not an installation of my own, nor do I develop anything for Sitecore (I do have admin access, however), so something along the lines of installing a plugin would be the best solution I reckon.

I've previously inserted the script in Sitecore 5.4, but not in a pretty way (editing XML files) and if a better solution could be found here too, that'd be pretty great.

***Update using Jens Mikkelsens answer in Sitecore Xpress 6:***

I tried placing the following in web.config:

```
<clientscripts>
  <everypage>
    <script src="/test.js" language="javascript" />
  </everypage>
  <htmleditor>
    <script src="/test.js" language="javascript" />
  </htmleditor>
</clientscripts>
```

Being a little bit overzealous (and wanting to make sure the test.js file can be found) I put a js.test in the following locations:

- inetpub\wwwroot\SitecoreWebsite\WebSite\sitecore\shell\Applications\Content Manager\
- inetpub\wwwroot\SitecoreWebsite\WebSite\sitecore\shell\Applications\
- inetpub\wwwroot\SitecoreWebsite\WebSite\sitecore\shell\
- inetpub\wwwroot\SitecoreWebsite\WebSite\sitecore\
- inetpub\wwwroot\SitecoreWebsite\WebSite\

Content of the test.js:

```
alert("Test [PATH TOKEN]");
```

Where the path token is just the parent folder name, so I know which test.js was loaded, e.g. inetpub\wwwroot\SitecoreWebsite\WebSite\sitecore\shell\Applications\Content Manager\test.js holds:

```
alert("Test Content Manager");
```

When I try to log in using the default Xpress admin user one of three things happens (in all three cases the frontend loads without errors, but no script present. I have **NOT** been able to determine when the errors happen, the only thing I can say for sure is that no errors occur when the test.js has not been included in web.config):

Case 1:

The content editor loads as expected, but no script is loaded. This happens most of the time when the clientscript have been included.

Case 2 - Server Error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Empty strings are not allowed.
Parameter name: value

Stack Trace: 

[ArgumentException: Empty strings are not allowed.
Parameter name: value]
   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNullOrEmpty(String argument, String argumentName) +241
   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.PageScriptManager.GetEveryPageScripts() +410
   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.PageScriptManager.GetScripts() +702
   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e) +62
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +143
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1477
```

Case 3 - Sitecore error:

```
A required license is missing
Most likely causes:
The resource you are trying to access requires the following license: Runtime.
```

I'm not sure whether or not Xpress simply doesn't support clientscripts, but even if it doesn't it is weird that some times the content editor loads.

***Update after testing in Sitecore 5.4 full version:***

It does indeed work to put a script tag inside the `<clientscripts>` section in web.config as Jens Mikkelsen answered. It is, however, neccessary to put it inside the subsection `<everypage>` to get it to appear on every single page in the backend, whereas `<htmleditor>` only works for the Telerik RadEditor popup window in Sitecore 5.4.

***Update after testing in Sitecore 6 full version:***

The same method as described for Sitecore 5.4 works for Sitecore 6 with the addition of little thing: `<script>` embedded in `<clienscripts>` now require a `key` attribute:

```
<clientscripts>
  <everypage>
    <script src="/test.js" language="javascript" key="test script" />
  </everypage>
</clientscripts>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to add the script with out modifying a file. However you can take a look at the `<clientscripts>` section in the web.config. There you can add scripts to be loaded. However I don't know if it will only load in the content editor.

I have experimented with this before, and I ended up using the above setting, but as I remember it also loaded on the Page Editor and the Desktop.

Comment: There's a sub-node under `<clientscripts>` called `<htmleditor>` -- I think that's where you'd add it.

Comment: I've tried this approach and run into some issues - check my question for updates on this.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use [this example code](http://firebreaksice.com/programmatically-add-controls-to-the-html-head-in-sitecore/) to add controls to the `<head>` on the front-end but instead alter it to use the `<renderContentEditor>` pipeline to somehow inject a new `<script>` tag into the editor.

Answer (score 0):

here is a good example of it [Injecting javascript and css to Sitecore Content Editor Page](http://sitecorepro.blogspot.com/2015/04/injecting-javascript-and-css-to.html)